# Python Create Combinations from Multiple Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas

Basically, I would like to create a new data frame from some existing data frames by creating all the possible column combinations. This is quite easy in `SAS` (or `expand.grid` function in `R`):

```
create table combine_var as
select *
from var_1, avar_2;
```

But I am not sure, what is the equalent way in Python. For instance, my data frame looks like:

```
var_1= pd.DataFrame.from_items([('val_1', [0.00789, 0.01448, 0.03157])])
var_2= pd.DataFrame.from_items([('val_2', [0.5, 1.0])])
```

And I expect the output is:

```
val_1   val_2
0.00789 0.5
0.00789 1.0
0.01448 0.5
0.01448 1.0
0.03157 0.5
0.03157 1.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `expand_grid` which is mentioned in [docs cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#creating-example-data):

```
def expand_grid(data_dict):
  rows = itertools.product(*data_dict.values())
  return pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=data_dict.keys())

expand_grid({'val_1': [0.00789, 0.01448, 0.03157], 'val_2' : [0.5, 1.0]})

In [107]: expand_grid({'val_1': [0.00789, 0.01448, 0.03157], 'val_2' : [0.5, 1.0]})
Out[107]:
     val_1  val_2
0  0.00789    0.5
1  0.00789    1.0
2  0.01448    0.5
3  0.01448    1.0
4  0.03157    0.5
5  0.03157    1.0
```

**EDIT**

For existing dataframes you first will need to create one dictionary from your dataframes. You could combine to one with one of the answers to that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression). Example for your case:

```
expand_grid(dict(var_1.to_dict('list'), **var_2.to_dict('list')))

In [122]: expand_grid(dict(var_1.to_dict('list'), **var_2.to_dict('list')))
Out[122]:
     val_1  val_2
0  0.00789    0.5
1  0.00789    1.0
2  0.01448    0.5
3  0.01448    1.0
4  0.03157    0.5
5  0.03157    1.0
```

Comment: Yes. I saw that code. But it needs to have a dictionary first. Just wondering if there exists a function which directly takes in data frames

Comment: you could convert them to dict and combine to one and pass to that function

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It seems like at this moment there is no build-in function in 'Pandas' to achieve this...

Comment: At least I don't know that. It's probably good to write a feature request for `pandas` package